EJS Rendering Issue: Status Column Value Not Displaying from MySQL Query
I am building a student management system using Node.js, MySQL, and EJS to render views. I want to display a list of students with their status value in a table, but the status column isn't showing any value, even though the data exists in the database.
MySQL Query:
SELECT s.stuNIC as NIC, s.stuUserName as username, u.intendedMajor, u.status
FROM student s 
JOIN university_registration u ON s.stuNIC = u.NIC;

The query works correctly when I run it directly on MySQL, and it returns the status value as expected.
EJS Template (uni-view-student.ejs):
<% data.forEach(function(student) { %>
    <tr onclick="window.location.href='/uni-notification/<%= student.NIC %>'">
        <td><%= student.NIC %></td>
        <td><%= student.username %></td>
        <td><%= student.intendedMajor %></td>
        <td><%= student.status %></td> <!-- This is not showing any value -->
    </tr>
<% }); %>

Node.js Code (server.js):
app.get('/uni-view-student', (req, res) => {
    const query = `
        SELECT s.stuNIC as NIC, s.stuUserName as username, u.intendedMajor, u.status
        FROM student s 
        JOIN university_registration u ON s.stuNIC = u.NIC
    `;
    connection.query(query, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error querying the database:', err);
            return res.status(500).send('Database query error');
        }
        res.render('uni-view-student', { data: results });
    });
});

Even though student.status is part of the query and has values in the database, the status column shows up empty on the page.
What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it so that the status value shows up correctly in the EJS template?



hmm did you also try to log the results before doing the res.render to double check

status is a reserved word in MySQL, you might need to add back tick to the column name in the query in server just in case it somehow messed up the result. Or, you can use alias to rename to something else

@LãNgọcHải if status being reserved word was the issue, then the query would have failed completely.

How do you map the json results to student object?

@Shadow that's why I said "just in case". Using reserved word will introduce avoidable headache so I just wanna remind OP. If my comment is unnecessary I'll remove it.
